# How does this for loop return the last line of a text file in Python?

Tags: python, file

```
filename = 'text_files/sample_text_file.txt'

with open(filename) as f:
    first_line = f.readline()
    for last_line in f:
        pass

print(last_line)
```

Comment: It reads all the lines and finally prints the last line it read, exactly which part(s) do you have problems understanding?

Comment: You're iterating over lines of text using `last_line` as temporary storage for value of current line. When you reach end of file loop stopped and `last_line` contatins last value which have been processed in loop which is last line in text file.

Comment: @Selcuk I do not understand how the code produces the last line of a text file--particularly from lines 4 to 6.

Answer (score 1):

The `for` loop iterates lines from the file. Each line is assigned to `last_line`, erasing any previous line that happened to be there. On end of file, the loop breaks without assigning anything to `last_line`. So, it will have the last thing assigned, which is the last line of the file. Unless the file only had one line - which is consumed by `first_line = f.readline()`. In that case, nothing is assigned to `last_line` and your program raises an exception.

Comment: How does the 'first_line = f.readline()' affect the for loop?

Comment: @itsnicolodasilva98 - `f.readline()` reads the first line of the file (or an empty string if the file is empty). When you switch to iterating the file object in the for loop, it continues from the current file position, which is the second line. Each trip round the loop consumes one line until end of file.

Comment: Is there another way I can get the last line of a text file using a similar structure as the existing code above?

Comment: That's a good way to do it unless the file is large. Alternately, you could open the file in binary mode, read the tail end of the file and `rfind` for the last b"\n" in the file. Its a bit complicated because you may have to repeat the tail end reads until you find the newline you are looking for. The method you have is easy and less likely to have bugs so unless you've got a performance problem, just stick with it.